# Trying to poll pop3 mailbox with spring integration

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I'm attempting to poll a mailbox with spring integration. I have this working with unit test using greenmail as the pop/smtp server.

Deploying to google appengine I'm running into issues as an AuthenticationException keeps being thrown:

```
ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; 
nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTH] Username and password not accepted. 
at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:131) 
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:243) 
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:262) 
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:391) 
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57) 
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) 
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55) 
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:385) 
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) 
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTH] Username and password not accepted. 
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:215) 
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) 
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246) 
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195) 
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:321) 
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:328) 
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:354) 
at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:112) ... 16 more
```

I pass the following parameters into the org.springframework.integration.mail.dsl.Mail.pop3InboundAdapter:

```
server - pop.gmail.com
port - 995
username - disbursement-qa@mycompany.com
password - pwd
```

I supply these parameters to the endpoint as well:

```
mail.pop3.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback=false
mail.pop3.socketFactory.port=995
```

I'm not sure if the email address of the mail account is the issue. The mailbox is hosted with google so I am supplying the account@domain.com

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: gmail doesn't allow JavaMail clients by default - you have to enable it in the account.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell is this under the settings/Forwarding and POP/IMAP?

Comment: No; see [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

Comment: That sorted, Many thanks @GaryRussell :-)